# How to create a jquery popup bubble for strongly typed views in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup, strongly-typed-view

Hi I am trying to create a jquery popup bubble for items created in a strongly typed view from a database in asp.net

I have found a number of examples but nothing that really helps. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of my strongly typed view with the table and items within the table columns:

```
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>
              name
          </th>

  <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

      <tr>
          <td>
              <%= (item.name) %>
          </td>
      </tr>

  <% } %>

  </table>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out how to do the popup bubble, or getting the data from the database, or displaying it in the strongly-typed view? You're probably going to need to be more specific if you want a good answer. Have you tried using a JQuery plugin like Q-tip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#gettingstarted)? If so, at what point did you get stuck?

Comment: sorry about the brief quesion. im strugglin with the bubble, and how I would actually link the information from the strongly typed view into the bubble

Comment: You may want to try loading in partial views via ajax into a jQuery.dialog box. I have never used jQuery.dialog before, so I don't actually know if it would be helpful :/.

Comment: Any chance you can link to which jQuery plugin you're trying to use to accomplish this?  There are two ways you could approach this.  Your popup bubble could be used to display content that's already on the page (perhaps hidden) or content retrieved from an ajax request.  Depending on which route you take the answer will probably be a little different.

Comment: ROMANARMY - I am trying to have a popup bubble for content already on the page, any more help would be great,here is the link to the popup bubble I was trying to acheive but with just jquery, anymore help on the subject would be great. http://maxvergelli.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/bubble-popups-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the bubble info somewhere on the page, inside a div tag perhaps. Put a class on the div tag that makes it (1) hidden and (2) absolutely positioned relative to the td tag.

Next, on the hover or click event of <%= item.name %>, you'll use jQuery to show() or hide() the popup.

```
<style>
    .myTable td { position:relative; top:0; left:0; }
    .myBubble { display:none; position:absolute; top:-100px; background:#CCC; }
</style>

<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div class="myTrigger"><%= (item.name) %></div>
           <div class="myBubble">
               <%= item.description %><br />
               <%= item.publishDate %>
           </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>

<script>

    // presuming you've already included a reference to the jQuery library...

    $('.myTrigger').hover( function () {
        // show the adjacent bubble content
        $(this).parent().find('.myBubble').show();  
    },   
    function () {
        // hide the adjacent bubble content
        $(this).parent().find('.myBubble').hide();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. this worked perfectly, very much appreciated since I am new to jquery and what it can do.